# ¿Cómo podría cambiar el authcontroller para que no logeara a usuarios inactivos?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

¿Qué tendría que cambiar para que después de eliminar a un usuario no me pudiera permitir logearme con el mismo en la aplicación?

Estos son mis middleware:

```
 <?php

namespace libreir\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
}



     <?php

    namespace libreir\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use libreir\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
<?php

namespace libreir\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Y los que he creado yo son:

```
    <?php

namespace libreir\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->rol == 0){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not admin access');
    }
}
```

y

```
 <?php

namespace libreir\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ClientMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->rol == 1){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home')->with('error','You have not client access');
    }
}
```

Las rutas las controlo en el archivo web.php, ej:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::resource('cliente/libro', 'LibroController');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir esta función en tu LoginController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
        $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
        /* Aquí es donde verificas que esté activo el usuario, asumiendo que 
           tengas un campo booleano active */
        if ($user->active) {
            Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));                
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);
        } else {
            return redirect(route('login'))
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'active' => trans('auth.active')
                ]);
           Sino vuelvo a la pagina de login y muestro el error correspondiente
        }
    }

    return redirect(route('login'))
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}
```

Al archivo resources\lang\en\auth.php le agrego al arreglo

```
'active' => 'El usuario está deshabilitado.',
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿de donde llamo a ese método?¿en el contructor tal vez? Por cierto, tengo un error donde dice Auth como que no lo encuentra, sabrías el por qué?

Comment: ese metodo no tienes ke llamarlo tu implicitamente es llamado por el mismo framework, el problema con el Auth es que tienes que incluir un use al comienzo del archivo **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;**

Answer (score 1):

Aunque el método de la otra respuesta funciona, una mejor forma sería incluir la verificación en el middleware `'auth'`, teniendo en cuenta que el middleware protege las rutas en cuestión y no solo el formulario de inicio de sesión (esto abriría un posible hueco de seguridad si la persona puede jugar con la sesión o algún otro parámetro):

Para ello debes definir manualmente o extender el middleware que incluye Laravel (modificar la siguiente línea en app\Http\Kernel.php):

```
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Revisa dicho código y agrega la verificación en el punto que consideres pertinente del middleware:

```
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->active) {
                return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
            } else {
                // usuario bloqueado
            }
        }
    }
```